# Disabling caching on the PHP Smarty templating engine?

Tags: php, smarty

For some reason I can't get Smarty to stop caching templates, which is really annoying when I'm making changes to templates during development. Can someone tell me where I'm going wrong in disabling all caching?:

```
$smarty                 =   new Smarty();
$smarty->template_dir   =   SMARTY_PATH."/templates";
$smarty->compile_dir    =   SMARTY_PATH."/templates_c";
$smarty->cache_dir      =   SMARTY_PATH."/cache";
$smarty->config_dir     =   SMARTY_PATH."/configs";
$smarty->cache_lifetime = 1;
$smarty->caching = 0;
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you want smarty to check, each time a template is used, if a new version of it exists (and re-compile it if it's the case), then you are probably looking for the [**`$compile_check`**](http://www.smarty.net/manual/en/variable.compile.check.php) option.

While developping, you might also be interested by this one : [**`$force_compile`**](http://www.smarty.net/manual/en/variable.force.compile.php) *(quoting)* :

> This forces Smarty to (re)compile
>   templates on every invocation.

Comment: Perfect, for some reason I never notice the $force_compile option in the manual. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

by default:

```
var $force_compile   =  false; / public $force_compile = false;
```

change above code to :

```
var $force_compile   =  true;  /   public $force_compile = true;
```